# Load html pages with css styles from jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a styles problem when loading headers, content and footers with jquery.
For some unknown problem, only the content is loaded, regardless of the styles.

The current code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#header").load("header/header.html");
            $("#footer").load("footer/footer.html");
            $("#content").load("content/content.html");
        });
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>

    <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Header.html
I get a error js:
(Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:XXXX/project/css.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.)
Although neither "src" or "href" works

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css.css">
</head>
<body class="bodyHeader">
    <hr>
    HEADER
    <hr>
</body>
</html>
```

css.css

```
.bodyHeader {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.bodyFooter {
  background-color: lightslategray;
}
.bodyContent {
  background-color: lightyellow;
}
```

I currently display text without styles.

HEADER

CONTENT

FOOTER

I want to visualize:

DIV [all content, measurements and styles] HEADER

DIV [all content, measurements and styles] CONTENT

DIV [all content, measurements and styles] FOOTER

Without any of them overlapping and respecting the distances.

Is it jquery problem?

Comment: First check the console and network tab in developer tools if there is a URL error for loading the stylesheet. And try giving type="text/css" in the link tag.

Comment: I already looked at it. There are none. I had an error with "href", I changed it to "src" and it did not give me any problem.

Comment: So is the CSS being loaded to your DOM?

Comment: _"I had an error with `href`, I changed it to `src`"_ - that of course makes zero sense. You can not just arbitrarily switch between those attributes however you like. The `link` element refers to external sources via the `href` attribute - and not something else.

Comment: But both the header, content and footer have their own css page independently.
How I do this?

Comment: _"because otherwise it gave a type error."_ - resulting from the fact that the browser got presented with an HTML document, and not actual CSS. And that HTML document would presumably have been your 404 page.

Comment: If I change to "href", it will give me the error that I published above and it does not solve anything even if putting href and type = "text / css" because it will continue giving error and not loading the files..

Comment: If `header/header.html` refers to the CSS _correctly_ with `../css.css`, then that same path will likely _not_ be correct, when you load this inside another document, that itself does _not_ reside on the `header` folder ...

Comment: _"If I change to "href", it will give me the error"_ - it will then give you that error, because the browser received something that was not a stylesheet, but was instructed to interpret it as a stylesheet. By changing `href` to `src`, the browser did not even _try_ to load anything (because it is a bogus attribute, in that context) - and _that's_ why you are not getting that error then, and _not_ because this attempt to "fix" the issue would have made any sense to begin with.

Comment: Okay. The problem may be in the route.
As the index is in the root and the css I have also tried to load it "../css.css" or "css.css" and it does not work either. Do I have to inject it with load by jquery?

Comment: Of course those both don't work, with those you would be looking in the current folder, resp. one level _up_ from the current folder. You do not want to go up - you want to go _down_, into the `header` folder. If the CSS file is located _in_ your `header` folder, then the correct path to it, _from_ the index file in the root directory's perspective, would of course be `header/css.css`

Comment: Agree. But now I am using a css that is located in the root with the index.html so I use the path ../css.css and it does not load the css either (as the background color of the body itself) (However, it does find the path, because from the dev tools I can see it)

Comment: I don't know what you think you see in dev tools, but you must be misinterpreting it, I suppose. If the CSS is in the _same_ folder as your index document, then of course `../css.css` is still wrong - because `../` _still_ means, "go one folder level up" - which from the root doesn't make sense to begin with, there _is_ nothing "above" the web root that you could reach via HTTP. With index document and CSS file in the same folder, this of course needs to be `css.css` (or `./css.css` at most, because one dot means "current folder".)

Comment: Agree. The path seen from the root (from the index.html) is now correct, but the styles are not loaded either.

Comment: Give me a moment, I know what happens.

Comment: Okay thank you very much.
I had 2 problems.
  - First I independently visualized the header.html
and the best thing was to do ../css.css. But you are right that it ends up calling index.html. However, I think the system should know how to interpret it.
I will play with the 2 URLS the "../css.css" as ".css.css", to display it on the page itself and where it is included. Why? to be able to work regardless of where it is imported.

Comment: - Second, I wrote it in the body (a fictitious body) because if I'm not mistaken, in a single html page, it can only contain one body (as long as an iframe is not included).
Then the body of the header.html never got to "paint" in the index.html.

I am an APPS programmer so this topic escapes me a bit.

Comment: Instead of painting or styling the header body, I just added a div, which will easily be interpreted by the index.html body. Thanks.